# Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop warning in NextJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js13

I'm getting the following warning in my Next.js web,

**app-index.js:31 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.**

I don't know what's the exact issue, since I have already tried a lot of things.

```
  <div className="hidden lg:block pt-1">
        <NavigationMenu>
          <NavigationMenuList className="space-x-14">
            <NavigationMenuItem className="text-[16px]">
              <Link href={`/shop`}>Shop</Link>
            </NavigationMenuItem>
              {navLinks != null
                ? navLinks.slice(0, 4).map((category: Category) => (
                    <NavigationMenuItem
                      className=" text-[18px]"
                      key={category.id}
                    >
                      <Link href={`/shop/${category.name}`} key={category.id}>
                        {category.name}
                      </Link>
                    </NavigationMenuItem>
                  ))
                : null}
          </NavigationMenuList>
        </NavigationMenu>
      </div>
```

The warning occurs if I puts this part in the code:

```
              {navLinks != null
                ? navLinks.slice(0, 4).map((category: Category) => (
                    <NavigationMenuItem
                      className=" text-[18px]"
                      key={category.id}
                    >
                      <Link href={`/shop/${category.name}`} key={category.id}>
                        {category.name}
                      </Link>
                    </NavigationMenuItem>
                  ))
                : null}
```

I have tried putting the keys on the mapped fields

Comment: can i see the code in the NavigationMenuItem component?

Comment: Are the IDs of the categories unique (and not `undefined`)?

Comment: @HenryWoody I'm fetching categories from sanity

Comment: The categories ids are all unique and non of them is undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React usually ask for a key prop whenever you are mapping as you have done above.
Besides, looks like you passed the key twice.
Try this code, should work

```
              {navLinks != null
                ? navLinks.slice(0, 4).map((category, index) => (
                    <NavigationMenuItem
                      className=" text-[18px]"
                  key={index}
                    >
                      <Link href={`/shop/${category.name}`}>
                        {category.name}
                      </Link>
                    </NavigationMenuItem>
                  ))
                : null}
```

You can also use your own code but this way

```
{navLinks != null
                ? navLinks.slice(0, 4).map((category: Category) => (
                    <NavigationMenuItem
                      className=" text-[18px]"
                      key={category.id}
                    >
                      <Link href={`/shop/${category.name}`}>
                        {category.name}
                      </Link>
                    </NavigationMenuItem>
                  ))
                : null}
```

Key props are usually passed once and into the parent jsx tag.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using an index as `key`.

Comment: Using **index** instead of **category.id** fixed the warning but not sure why, since all ids of categories are unique                                                                                       ` (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0
: 
{_id: '64b8689c-decb-41b6-b94d-2d07c1342d47', name: 'Boys'}
1
: 
{_id: '8ef8408b-f3f6-43c7-992b-4d73bf4eb580', name: 'Girls'}
2
: 
{name: 'Men', _id: '953835a2-9b40-41d9-894a-36ed7b1de48c'} `